# Wait for return statement from "then" of angular $q.all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function and inside the function, I have a $q.all call as follows

```
function test()
{
    $q.all(promises).then(function(response)
    {
         return response;
    });
}
```

But my function doesn't return anything as it is not waiting for the response. Also, what should I do if I have to return from the `then` part of a $q.all inside a $q.all

Comment: What Chev wrote. You have to wrap your head around this promise thingy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return the promise itself and chain `.then` handlers from there.

```
function test() {
  return $q.all(promises);
}

test().then(function (response) {
  // do stuff with response
});
```

Returning a promise from a `.then` handler adds it to the outer promise chain, so you can chain promises together like so:

```
function test() {
  $q.all(promises).then(function (response) {
    return $q.all(morePromises);
  });
}

test().then(function (morePromisesResponse) {
  // do stuff
});
```

You can also just return a non-promise value from a `.then` handler and it is wrapped in a promise and returned to the outer chain so you can get the value in the next `.then` handler.

```
function test() {
  $q.all(promises).then(function (response) {
    return 123;
  });
}

test().then(function (result) {
  // result is 123
});
```

I'm happy to give a more specific answer if you're still confused. I'd just need a code sample from you and what you're trying to accomplish so I can help.

Comment: Happy to help :)